# Add PHP Echo to End of WordPress Titles

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Editing my theme to place a facebook icon immediately to the right of my page titles.

With the old icon (HTML) the following code worked and the icon was placed beside the title:

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'catch-adaptive' ); ?><a class="genericon_parent genericon genericon-facebook-alt" title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/karen.b.russell.54" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.facebook.com/karen.b.russell.54'); return false;"><span class="screen-reader-text">Facebook</span></a></h1>
```

Now I am trying to use the php code given to me by a plugin:

```
<?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS();?>
```

I've done this:

```
<header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS();?></h1>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

The problem is that the echo is displaying the icon below the page title instead right beside it.

How do I position the icon to the right of the title using this plugin's PHP code?

You can view the live site with the new misplaced icon at http://healthylifeadvisors.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works;

```
<header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title" style="float: left;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div style="display: inline-block;"><?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS(); ?></div>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

Obviously if you can easily edit the CSS files, you could add the following statements (instead of putting them inline in the HTML), like so;

```
.entry-title {
     float: left;
}
.entry-header > div {
     display: inline-block;
}
```